# How to get name of permission for UI?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-permissions, kotlin-android-extensions

I would like to be clear when I ask the user for permissions. For that, I would like to know what is the name of the permission as the user sees it in Android settings.
I tried the following code

```
val pi: PermissionInfo =
            activity.getPackageManager().getPermissionInfo(permission, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
val s1 = pi.toString()
val s2 = activity.getResources().getString(pi.labelRes)
val s3 = activity.getResources().getString(pi.descriptionRes)
```

The result for permission="android.permission.SEND_SMS" is

s1 = "PermissionInfo{1724d0d android.permission.SEND_SMS}"

s2 = "send and view SMS messages"

s3 = "Allows the app to send SMS messages. This may result in unexpected charges. Malicious apps may cost you money by sending messages without your confirmation."

But for the user the name is just "SMS". How  do I get this string?

Of course I could simply write "SMS", but I would like it in generic permission code, and also to be correlated with localization, Android version, etc.

Comment: "But for the user the name is just "SMS"" -- that is a permission group, not a permission. In the Settings UI, it may be presented as a "permission", but from the standpoint of the Android SDK, it is a permission group.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I was not aware. But then why do I get pi.group="android.permission-group.UNDEFINED"?

Comment: There had been some (inexplicable) restrictions on finding out the relationship between permissions and groups at runtime. In your case, you should be able to identify your relevant permission groups manually and switch to using [`getPermissionGroupInfo()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getPermissionGroupInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)).